# Как создавать и обращаться к View MS SQL в EntityFramework 6?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

Суть проблемы как всегда в производительности, очень много запросов происходит к базе данных по выборке. Сделал удобное представление в самой базе данных, теперь выборка происходит одним запросом.

Вопрос как сделать View при инициализации базы данных при подходе COdeFirst?
Если первое сделать невозможно(как я сделал вручную через MS SQL Management Studio), как получить к ней доступ в коде(поскольку CodeFirst, то система видит только те таблицы, которые представлены моделями)?

Comment: в миграции можно выполнить любой `sql` скрипт, после создания view таким образом, к ней можно будет обратиться например так: `_context.Database.SqlQuery<КлассМодели>("select * from ВашаВью")`

Comment: Оно то понятно, я могу любой запрос к базе данных сделать, но вопрос заключается в том, как их получить, сущность-то не определяется для View.

Comment: [SqlQuery](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx) позволяет получить результат `sql` запроса в виде заполненного экземпляра класса, класс для материализации конечно придется создать, а вот в `DbContext` его добавлять не надо

Comment: У меня база с IdentityFramework, там метода SqlQuery нету.

Comment: в Вашем проекте контекст наследуется от `IdentityDbContext`который в свою очередь наследуется от `DbContext`?

Comment: Да, я ошибся, проблема не в Identity, я так понимаю метода просто нет в Core 2.0.

Comment: да, *печально* что в `core` убрали возможность выполнить произвольный sql запрос, попробуйте сделать как советуют [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412268/5610621)

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз подумал про POCO объект.

Comment: не за что, после того как найдете решение своей проблемы не забудьте опубликовать ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена в предрелизной версии EF Core 2.1 - добавили поддержку view